# Html.ActionLink returning unstyled PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco7

I'm rendering an ActionLink on a view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Enrol Now", "popForm", "EnrolFormSurface", new { @qualID=e.qualNode})</p>
```

Which successfully redirects to the ActionResult on the controller:

```
    public ActionResult popForm(int qualID)
    {
        ICTEnrolmentFormViewModel m = new ICTEnrolmentFormViewModel();
        //I'm doing some stuff here with the incoming parameter which I've commented out for ease

        return PartialView("Enrol", m);

    }
```

But the partial view (although successfully rendering) contains no styling (which should be inheriting from the it's parent)...could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: If you're linking the user to a page, shouldn't it be a `View` and not a `PartialView`?  You'd want a full view so it would include the layout, which is generally where the styling is applied.  A partial view is meant to be only a part of another view, not a view in and of itself.

Comment: If I try to return the view the application can't find the view. The master / child relationship is configured inside Umbraco

Comment: Sounds like you need to use AJAX, because standard `ActionLink` expects to redirect for full view. Also, partial view doesn't reference layout file where CSS & JS files are included, hence the styling broken when you returning partial view.